# Qt webserver vs. mobile browsers

Tags: android, qt, http, webserver, opera

I created a very simple webserver in qt for very specific needs.
As simple as that let us have an http request:
 GET /cover.png HTTP 1.1

the response arrives perfectly on desktop computers. when i try to get the image from a mobile device (i tried more but lets say android+opera) the image won't load. in opera, it loads only about 1/3 of the picture while on the sever side qt claims all the bytes were sent ok.

i noticed it depends on the size of the image: ~4k is ok, but 12k is "too much"

i know opera on android CAN load much bigger images so i must mess up something in the response. but at the same time, again on my desktop, all the major browsers are all good.

i noticed after the partially loaded image has been displayed, opera opens a new tcp connection tovards my server, but sends nothing!
is it trying to load the image in chunks? is there such thing in http?

i am really getting lost about what is up here...

Update:
If the file is big enough it won't work in a desktop environment eighter!
Experienced limitations:
Desktop: max. 65339 bytes
Mobile:  max. 12834 bytes

Since the limits are not the same at all, I don't think it's Qt related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out:
The download of the image stops because the tcp connection is closed too early by my server. This is strange, because I send responses like this:

```
socket->write( message );
if( !socket->waitForBytesWritten( 5000 ) )
{ puts( "Timed out!" ); }
emit sent();
```

It doesn't work this way. QTcpSocket is a buffered IODevice, so it should print if sending times out. Maybe I misunderstand something about waitForBytesWritten().
So it turns out it IS a Qt issue after all. If I don't delete the socket after sending it works Ok.
The size limit difference for desktop and mobile browsers was about the speed they can achieve (how many bytes can it receive before I delete the socket).

So how can I be sure when all bytes has been really sent to the client?

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in line 241:

```
int len = 4096;
```

should be:

```
int len = 32768;
```

Comment: This question got me very curious on the subject. How were you able to diagnose it I don't see any code?